# Which is correct to compute derivative of $\frac{d\left(x^{T}a\right)}{dx}$?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrices, derivatives, partial-derivative

I have two vector $x$ and $a$ defined as: 
$x=
\left(\begin{array}{c}
x_1\\
x_2\\
\vdots\\
x_n
\end{array}\right)
$;
$a=
\left(\begin{array}{c}
a_1\\
a_2\\
\vdots\\
a_n
\end{array}\right).
$

Defined  that
$$
x^{T}a=\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}a_{i}
$$

Which is correct solution of 
$\frac{d\left(x^{T}a\right)}{dx}$?

Solution 1:

$$
\frac{d\left(x^{T}a\right)}{dx}=\left(\begin{array}{c}
a_{1}\\
a_{2}\\
\vdots\\
a_{n}
\end{array}\right)=a.
$$

or
Solution 2:
$$
\frac{d\left(x^{T}a\right)}{dx}=a^T.
$$

As my understand, I think the first solution is correct.

Comment: @user251257: I just want to get derivative of $x^Ta$

Comment: So, What is corrected solution for above? Is it $a^T$

Comment: sorry. My bad. See TeXminator's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The (Fréchet) derivative $Df(x)$ of a function $f:V\to W$ between Banach spaces $V$ and $W$ is a special bounded linear operator $Df(x):V\to W$. In your case, $V=\mathbb{R}^n$, $W=\mathbb{R}$, that is, $Df(x)$ is a linear functional on $\mathbb{R}^n$. Here, $f(x)=x^Ta$, so $Df(x)(h)=a^Th$. In finite-dimensional spaces, we always have matrix representations for linear operators. For the derivative, this matrix is the Jacobian $J_f(x)$ which is, in our example, $J_f(x)=a^T$, in order to have $Df(x)(h)=J_f(x)h$. (Application of a linear operator becomes matrix multiplication.)

In Cartesian coordinates, the gradient of a scalar function is the column vector of the partial derivatives. In your case $\nabla f(x)=a$.

Comment: So my first solution is correct?

Comment: @mjohn1282 it depends on your convention. Is $\frac{df(x)}{dx}$ the gradient or the Jacobian?

Comment: It is gradient, Sir

Comment: @mjohn1282: So it is $a$.